# How to notify driver about the rider using firebase cloud messaging?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am making an app for taxi services. I need to add a feature like as soon as user click call driver button then a notification is sent to the respective driver selected within the range of 5 km. The driver will have only 15 seconds to accept the request otherwise, another driver will be notified.

I have implemented all this using firebase database. I have successfully implemented the part of calling the driver from rider app and assigning the closest driver to the customer. I have done this by creating fields like drivers working, drivers available.

There are children of driver working field specifying the customer id, latitude, longitude. As soon as the driver is assigned a customer it is moved from available to work.

Now I want that driver should not be automatically moved to drivers working

First off all a request should be sent to him for accepting the ride or not..and on ok then the driver will be moved to working.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. You're question doesn't have a clear question and doesn't show any attempts at a solution. Try reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and editing your question

Comment: Any hint about using FCM server or App server for the purpose.?

Comment: We're trying to tell you that you need to read the help section then edit your question before the community can help you.